# Concorse web-ui container keeps dying

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, concourse

I'm trying to test out concourse on an ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance.  I am attempting to use the containerized version of the software with the docker-compose example shown here in the [documentation.](https://concourse.ci/docker-repository.html) However on any attempt the 
`concourse-web` container fails after about 15 seconds.  I am just looking for a quick easy setup of concourse on ec2 so I can test it out, how can I get it running using the containerized version of the software?

**More info:**

Here is the script I am using to get it up and running:

```
mkdir concourse
cd concourse
mkdir -p keys/web keys/worker

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ./keys/web/tsa_host_key -N ''
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ./keys/web/session_signing_key -N ''

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ./keys/worker/worker_key -N ''

cp ./keys/worker/worker_key.pub ./keys/web/authorized_worker_keys
cp ./keys/web/tsa_host_key.pub ./keys/worker

# for ec2
export CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL=$(wget -q -O - http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)

#creating docker compose file
echo 'concourse-db:
  image: postgres:9.5
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: concourse
    POSTGRES_USER: concourse
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
    PGDATA: /database

concourse-web:
  image: concourse/concourse
  links: [concourse-db]
  command: web
  ports: ["8080:8080"]
  volumes: ["./keys/web:/concourse-keys"]
  environment:
    CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME: concourse
    CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD: changeme
    CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL: "${CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL}"
    CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_DATA_SOURCE: |
      postgres://concourse:changeme@concourse-db:5432/concourse?sslmode=disable

concourse-worker:
  image: concourse/concourse
  privileged: true
  links: [concourse-web]
  command: worker
  volumes: ["./keys/worker:/concourse-keys"]
  environment:
    CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST: concourse-web' > docker-compose.yml

docker-compose up -d
```

However about 15 seconds after doing a `docker-compose up -d` the `concorse_concourse-web_1` container stops running and I cannot connect to it through a browser at any point.  Here are the docker logs of the container at the end right when it fails (there's more but I cant fit it all so just test it yourself to see the full logs):

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x5e093a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0xfba6c0, 0xc820016070)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
github.com/concourse/atc/atccmd.(*ATCCommand).constructAPIHandler(0xc82023c608, 0x7ff484d1b5d0, 0xc8200501e0, 0xc82026f0e0, 0xc8202c9300, 0x7ff484d1d858, 0xc82030c5c0, 0x7ff484d1d980, 0xc8202afda0, 0x7ff484d1d958, ...)
        /tmp/build/9674af12/concourse/src/github.com/concourse/atc/atccmd/command.go:787 +0x121a
github.com/concourse/atc/atccmd.(*ATCCommand).Runner(0xc82023c608, 0xc820270d30, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /tmp/build/9674af12/concourse/src/github.com/concourse/atc/atccmd/command.go:221 +0xe44
main.(*WebCommand).Execute(0xc82023c608, 0xc820270d30, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /tmp/build/9674af12/gopath/src/github.com/concourse/bin/cmd/concourse/web.go:54 +0x297
github.com/concourse/bin/vendor/github.com/vito/twentythousandtonnesofcrudeoil.installEnv.func2(0x7ff484d0b5e0, 0xc82023c608, 0xc820270d30, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /tmp/build/9674af12/gopath/src/github.com/concourse/bin/vendor/github.com/vito/twentythousandtonnesofcrudeoil/environment.go:30 +0x81
github.com/concourse/bin/vendor/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags.(*Parser).ParseArgs(0xc8200512c0, 0xc82000a150, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /tmp/build/9674af12/gopath/src/github.com/concourse/bin/vendor/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags/parser.go:312 +0xa34
github.com/concourse/bin/vendor/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags.(*Parser).Parse(0xc8200512c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /tmp/build/9674af12/gopath/src/github.com/concourse/bin/vendor/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags/parser.go:185 +0x9b
main.main()
        /tmp/build/9674af12/gopath/src/github.com/concourse/bin/cmd/concourse/main.go:29 +0x10d
```

Also after trying to stop and remove the containers the concorse_concourse-worker_1 container cannot be removed and shows up in a `docker ps -a` as Dead.  The following error message occurs when attempting to remove it:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-59-167:~/concorse$ docker rm a005503d568b
Error response from daemon: Driver aufs failed to remove root filesystem a005503d568b4931f860334e95ff37265dc0913083d3592f0291e023275bbf20: rename /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/9bcff3a39934ea3525bf8a06ef900bf9dfba59a5187747beb65e9ba5709ebf75 /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/9bcff3a39934ea3525bf8a06ef900bf9dfba59a5187747beb65e9ba5709ebf75-removing: device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://concourse.ci/docker-repository.html) on this has been updated with more succinct instructions.